# How to use below code in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
delete asp_testtable
where  userid='XYZ' 
and    SL=12
and    userAmount=13
```

where:

- `asp_testtable` is the table name
- `userid` is a column of type `varchar`
- `SL` is a column of type `bigint`
- `userAmount` is a column of type `decimal`

These are the three steps i followed but non of them are working

Step 1:

```
asp_testtable map = DBContext.asp_testtable.RemoveRange(DBContext.asp_testtable.Where(c => c.userid == tbuserid.Text.Trim() && c.SlNo == Convert.ToInt64(lbSlNo.Text.ToString()) && c.userAmount == Convert.ToInt16(ddluserAmount.SelectedValue.ToString()))).SingleOrDefault();

DBContext.asp_testtable.Remove(map);
```

Step 2:

```
var y = (from x in asp_testtable where x.userid == tbuserid.Text.Trim() && x.SlNo == Convert.ToInt64(lbSlNo.Text) && x.userAmount == Convert.ToInt16(ddluserAmount.SelectedValue) select x.FeeMappingSlNo).First();

DBContext.asp_testtable.RemoveRange(y);
```

step 3:

```
feedetail = new asp_testtable()
{
    userid = tbuserid.Text.Trim(),
    SlNo = Convert.ToInt64(lbSlNo.Text),
    userAmount = Convert.ToInt16(ddluserAmount.SelectedValue)
};

DBContext.asp_testtable.Remove(feedetail);
```

Comment: Please post some code - eg. What have you tried? What worked, what didn't work? At least show some effort on your part to figure out the problem.

Comment: here is the which i have tried `asp_testtable map = DBContext.asp_testtable.RemoveRange(DBContext.asp_testtable.Where(c => c.userid == tbuserid.Text.Trim() && c.SlNo == Convert.ToInt64(lbSlNo.Text.ToString()) && c.userAmount == Convert.ToInt16(ddluserAmount.SelectedValue.ToString()))).SingleOrDefault();<br/>
DBContext.asp_testtable.Remove(map);`

Comment: This really needs expanding, I get that you're trying to get some SQL converted to use for entity framework; but the question indicates a lack of thought and knowledge both of EF and of stackoverflow requirements see: http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/ and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to familiarise yourself with the standards the community like to see questions adhere to.

Comment: Its a good idea to show the model as well.

Comment: I suggest adding that to the question

Comment: @user3128590: Thanks for adding this. I removed my downvote and voted to reopen. Please take a look how I formatted your question. You are using a lot of HTML while that is unnecessary.

Comment: Patrick Hofman, thanks for removing downvote and also for formatting my question

Answer (score 1):

```
context.asp_testtable.Select(item => item.userid == "XYZ" && item.SL = 12 && 
item.userAmount == 13).ToList().ForEach(context.asp_testtable.DeleteObject);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Find the relevant items and remove them using `DeleteObject`

Comment: DeleteObject is not supported in my project

Comment: Use `RemoveRange` then, and specify the `EF` in the question.

Comment: Dear Ofiris, I have shown all the step's which i have used

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string DeleteStatement = "DELETE FROM asp_testtable " + 
    "WHERE userid = 'XYZ' AND SL=12 AND userAmount=13 ";

yourcontext.Database.SqlQuery(DeleteStatement);
```